# How to move InverseKinematics 2D via code?? Unity2D (Platformer)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inverse-kinematics

Is there a way to move the Inverse Kinematics(CCD) from arm, in this case, via code? The goal is to move the IK Target in the direction of the mouseclick

A video of what i want to do via code, in runtime:
https://vimeo.com/489165740

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code, or specific examples you can share? Your question is lacking detail, consider reading this post on creating a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Here is a video of what im doing(https://vimeo.com/489165740), i already did some animations for my guy, and what i want is to do what im doing in the beggining of the video but in runtime, through code, so  my arm points to wherever i click. I tried setting the Effector Object position itself, to the mouse direction, but appears in runtime all bones position are locked and cannot be moved if not by the IK Target out of runtime

Comment: We don't put "solved" in the question.  Just accept your answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: it says i cant Accept my own question before 2days has passed, so i wrote there for now

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, i deleted all the IK objects from the arm, (solver,effector and target), recreated them and now the Target moves position with code just fine.